# Как узнать время жизни csrf токена в laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, token, csrf

One page application, все на аяксе, возникает проблема что если страница долго открыта и без действий токен протухает и user не может понять что случилось, потому что яваскрипт только в консоль ошибки бросает, а обрабатывать везде в ручную эту проблему просто не хочется. Попытался аяксом дергать периодически сервер и запрашивать текущий токен. Создалось впечатление что токен перестал протухать, возвращается один и тот же токен если сервер видит какие то запросы с текущей страницы. Не понятно как ведет себя этот токен в ларавел в целом. На странице логина не приятная ситуация - после 10-15 минут простоя - при попытке залогиниться жалуется что токен протух. Подскажите где настройки для управление csrf токеном, и если их нет, то какими командами можно более тонко управлять этим самым токеном?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой [Laravel Caffeine](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine). Она как раз создавалась с этой целью,

Установка библиотеки:

```
composer require genealabs/laravel-caffeine
```

Потом в `config/app.php` добавьте следующее в `providers`:

```
// 'providers' => [
    GeneaLabs\LaravelCaffeine\Providers\LaravelCaffeineService::class,
// ],
```

Потом в `/app/Http/Kernel.php` добавьте следующее:

```
// protected $middleware = [
    \GeneaLabs\LaravelCaffeine\Http\Middleware\LaravelCaffeineDripMiddleware::class,
// ];
```

Только учтите что этот вариант для версии 5.1 и 5.3, для 5.2 есть другой гайд, подробней читайте на странице библиотеки.